# save value in <a> attribute and get the value again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to store a value in  attribute  or button it doesn't matter and i need to get that value again.

My approach that i need when any one click that link or button i will get the value and do some staff.The problem here is that i can't get the value again.

Here is what did :

```
$.each(result[1], function (index, val) {
    $("<a href='#' class='track_it' val=" + val.locations + ">CLICK !</a>").appendTo(".my_data_table");
});
```

Where locations is a `list of dicts` **sorry i'm pythonic**.

when i try to do this :

```
$(".track_it").click(function () {
    console.log($(".track_it").attr("value"));
});
```

i do not get the value right, just something like `[objc` it's string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did this:

```
$("  <a href='#' class='track_it' val=" + val.locations + ">CLICK !</a>")
```

JavaScript turned `val.locations` into a string. It becomes `[object Object]` and becomes part of `<a>`'s HTML.

To avoid that, use [`jquery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
$('<a ...stuff... />').data('val', val.locations).appendTo(".my_data_table")
```

To retrieve the value, simply use `jquery.data` again, but without the second argument.

```
console.log($(".track_it").data('val'));
```

Comment: that would be great if i just adding 1 element in the loop ..what if we are talking about a  table and we adding data to each cell in the loop ?! how could we do that ?!

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can use `data` attribute to set new attribute. The syntax is quite simple as well: `$('.myElement').data('myAttribute', 'someValue')`, and you can retrieve the value using `$('.myElement').data('myAttribute');`

### Edit

You can do this in a loop, all you have to do is replace the line in your loop with this:

```
$.each(result[1], function (index, val) {
    $("<a href='#' class='track_it' data-location=" + val.locations + ">CLICK !</a>").appendTo(".my_data_table");
});
```

And then retrieve it this way:

```
$(".track_it").click(function () {
console.log($(this).data("location"));
});
```

Comment: but i need t set the value in the loop because it's related with other staff

Comment: You can do it in a loop as well, the syntax does not changes.

Comment: the attribute is not exist in the first place how could i use .myElement if i add it in the loop ?!

Comment: that would be great if i just adding 1 element in the loop ..what if we are talking about a table and we adding data to each cell in the loop ?! how could we do that ?!

Comment: Well you can add as many data as you want. It just has to be unique in your element. Not in your DOM.

Comment: This will not work it's almost the same of what i did.

Comment: Well what is the problem then,